# How to have different style files in multilingual website using Drupal?

Tags: i18n-l10n, theming

I have been developing a multilingual website using Drupal 6. The languages are English and Spanish. I want to have some different backgrounds and css for them. But both use just style.css.

How can I create different style.css file for them? For example style-sp.css for Spanish one and en-style.css for English one ?

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this in template.php:
you have to copt css file in themefolder/css.

```
    function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
        global $language ;
        $lang_name = $language->language ;
        if ($lang_name=='en')
        drupal_add_css(path_to_theme(). '/css/en-style.css');
        elseif ($lang_name=='sp')
        drupal_add_css(path_to_theme(). '/css/style-sp.css');
        $vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css(); //  use drupal_get_css() to add new css
}
```

so you have one of css files related to current page language.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and put my theme instead of 'yourtheme'. Cleared cache, but it doesn't work.

Comment: i 'm sorry. you are using drupal 6.i think you have to use  'yourtheme_preprocess_page'. let me know if it works.

Comment: I use preprocess_page function, it goes through it but doesn't add style file.

Comment: i edited code and tested by myself and it works.